# Intervention Image Class not returning any exif data - Laravel 4

Tags: php, image-processing, laravel, laravel-4, exif

working with image uploads using Laravel 4 and intervention Image.

It uploads fine, but has issues with orientation. There is an auto orientate function (->orientate());

but that didnt work. So, looking at the docs i tried to read the exif data to see what was happening.

I used this in my view:

```
$data = Image::make('uploads/coverimages/IMG_1126.JPG')->exif('model');

print $data;
```

But it returns nothing, as in nothing is displayed. No errors at all, just nothing.

Any ideas?

Edit: The image has been taken from a DSLR and simply dragged into the folder. No uploading / resizing etc so it WILL have exif data. Have also tried another method (->width) and it returns a value so i know the functions are working.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
Note: PHP must be compiled in with --enable-exif to use this method. Windows users must also have the mbstring extension enabled.
```

Comment: That does look to be the issue. Am currently trying to figure out how to do so. Thanks.

Comment: If you got Imagick you can use the getImageProperties('*') method on your Imagick object.

Comment: I have checked my phpinfo and it shows exif is enabled. Shall have to look more into this.

Comment: To be sure you can check the [exif_read_data()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) function. It's what Intervention is using (for as far as I saw as quick)

Comment: Caps lock was the answer. The first letter of the exif type must be capitalized. -.-